# PHP NestedSet move nodes

Tags: php, mysql, nested

please, could you provide me your help?
I'm trying to make my own small NestedSet library. Everything is ok, except three methods: move after, move before and move inside. I don't know why, but it still badly recount **lft** and **rgt** for nested set items... but I can't see any problem in my code...
Could you help me, what I'm doing bad or provide some example nested set library, which implements this 3 methods to inspire a edit my code? 
Thank you very much.

I use Laravel5 DB class methods, but there is no problem to use plain mysql queries.

Here is my code:

```
/**
     *
     * @param $targetId
     * @param $pos
     * @param int $levelUp
     */
    public function moveNode($targetId, $pos, $levelUp = 0){

        $width = $this->rgt - $this->lft + 1; // get moved item width
        $target = $this->getLeaf($targetId);

        switch($pos) {
            case 'after':
                $newLeftPos = $target->rgt + 1;
                break;
            case 'before':
                $newLeftPos = $target->lft;
                break;
            case 'inside':
                $newLeftPos = $target->lft + 1;
                break;
        }

        $moveLength = $newLeftPos - $this->lft; // get length of move

        $newNodeLvl = $target->lvl + $levelUp;
        $nodeLvlDifference = $newNodeLvl - $this->lvl;

        // get moving node items
        // store ids of moving node items into array to use it in moving node....
        $ids = [];
        $primaryKeyName = $this->primaryKey;
        $node = DB::table($this->table)
            ->where('lft', '>=', $this->lft)
            ->where('rgt', '<=', $this->rgt)
            ->get();
        foreach($node as $nodeItem) {
            $ids[] = $nodeItem->$primaryKeyName;
        }


        // FIRSTLY I WANT TO DELETE OLD NODE SPACE SO I WILL DECREASE lft > $this->rgt AND rgt > $this->rgt BY WIDTH OF
        // MOVING NODE
        DB::table($this->table)
            ->where('lft', '>', $this->rgt)
            ->decrement('lft', $width);
        DB::table($this->table)
            ->where('rgt', '>', $this->rgt)
            ->decrement('rgt', $width);


        // NOW I WILL MAKE FREE SPACE FOR MY NODE
        // SO I NEED TO INCREASE lft AND rgt OF ITEMS WHICH ARE > $newLeftPos
        // I WILL INCREASE IT AT EACH ITEMS EXCEPT ITEMS WITH id IN $ids ARRAY (ids of items in moving node)
        DB::table($this->table)
            ->where('lft', '>=', $newLeftPos)
            ->whereNotIn($primaryKeyName, $ids)
            ->increment('lft', $width);
        DB::table($this->table)
            ->where('rgt', '>=', $newLeftPos)
            ->whereNotIn($primaryKeyName, $ids)
            ->increment('rgt', $width);

        // NOW I WILL MOVE NODE TO ITS NEW POSITION
        // ALSO I CHANGE NODE ITEMS lvl
        $nodeItems = DB::table($this->table)
            ->whereIn($primaryKeyName, $ids);
        $nodeItems->increment('rgt', $moveLength);
        $nodeItems->increment('lft', $moveLength);
        if($newNodeLvl !== 0) {
            $nodeItems->increment('lvl', $nodeLvlDifference);
        }


    }
```

Comment: So finally I found help in this library:
https://github.com/olimortimer/ci-nested-sets/blob/master/Nested_set.php